# Magento issues when saving Categories

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.3

I have some issues saving categories in Magento 2.3.5, when I click save after changing the SEO information (Meta Title, Meta description and Meta Keywords) gives me this error.

> Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\FileInfo::removeStorePath() must be of the type string, array given, called in /home/adminpsol2016/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/FileInfo.php on line 167

[image]

here you can see a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Magento 2.3.5 Categories issues]

Comment: I would recommend consulting the documentation for Magento. The error is pretty clear to me, but I don't know why it would be receiving an array rather a string via the administration interface unless you're somehow passing in an array manually. If this is not the case, it is a defect in Magento (assuming you haven't mucked about with their code) and you should contact their support team.

Comment: Thank you, haven't touch the code, i am just passing a string in the meta title field and the keywords.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? I'm having same problem

Comment: Hi there, I got same issue, did you find a solution for this @Ranganathan?

Comment: Oddly enough, I have this issue too but in my local environment only (the deployed app allows to upload images just fine)

Answer (score 7):

This gave me quite a headache but finally managed to get to the bottom of it; my case is as follow:

Repro:

- add a custom category attribute with `backend_model` := `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image`
- Have the category form save operation fail for whatever reason (e.g. have a plugin on the category model save function which throws an Exception)

Reason:

If you look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php#L240 you'll see that this has the effect of storing the entire POST data of the current form request to session (also the `LocalizedException` block does the same).
Later on, this data is restored in https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php#L95 *and immediately after* the form information for the `image` attribute is stripped/cleared.
This of course does *not* handle any custom attribute of Image type we might have defined for our category entity.

Solution:

I added an `after*` plugin (in `adminhtml` area only) on `\Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager::__call`, where I explicitly check that the invoked method is `getCategoryData`: if this is the case, I fetch all the custom category image attributes, and strip them from the returned array like `Category/Edit` does.

This way any further exception message is correctly displayed in the backoffice (granted it extends `LocalizedException`)

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on the answer from Francesco Salvi which really helped me with the same problem, this is how we implemented that solution:

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager">
        <plugin name="pluginNameGoesHere" type="Vendor\Namespace\Plugin\StripCustomImage" />
    </type>
</config>
```

plugin/StripCustomImage.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Plugin;

class StripCustomImage
{
    public function after__call($method, $response, ...$args)
    {
        if ($args[0] === 'getCategoryData') {
            if (isset($response['widget_image']['delete'])) {
                $response['widget_image'] = null;
            } else {
                unset($response['widget_image']);
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Where 'widget_image' is the attribute name for the custom category image we created in another module that was causing us the pain.